# О правильности оформления устойчивых сочетаний

Tags: запятые, грамматика, согласование, подлежащее

***Не что иное, как огромная скала(,) преграждала  нам путь.***

Что здесь является подлежащим, скала или все сочетание?  Можно ли обособлять оборот с союзом КАК, ведь запятая будет разделять согласованные в роде подлежащее и сказуемое?

Answer (score 1):

Да можно, здесь весь оборот - подлежащее. Сам удивлен!

Comment: Спасибо вам за ответ. А давайте рассмотрим такое предложение: Не сила, а ум побеждает.Здесь подлежащее выражено противопоставлением:  два однородных члена, связанных союзом А и частицей НЕ. Как мы видим, запятой там нет.Наш оборот речи построен по тому же принципу, только на месте союза А стоит союз КАК. Но это тоже противопоставление, именно поэтому мы выбираем частицу НЕ: Не что иное, а огромная скала (,) преграждала нам путь.

Comment: По существующим правилам оборот с  союзом КАК обособляется, но на каком основании? Кроме того, разве можно разделять запятой подлежащее и сказуемое? Да еще неправильное согласование! Получается, что мы согласуем сказуемое с обособленным оборотом? Но ведь все эти проблемы можно было бы решить,  просто убрав запятую. А какое решение предложили бы  нам вы?

Comment: Вообще, я считал раньше и сейчас, что союзы "А" и как", различаются. Даже если подставить в предложение: Не сила, как ум побеждает. Или: 
Не что иное, а огромная скала, преграждала нам путь.

Comment: А вот запятую все же надо оставить, потому что хоть это и оборот, он же является членом

Comment: Возражаю. 1. Союзы многозначны, как и другие слова. В данном случае сравнительный союз КАК равен сопоставительному союзу А (значения похожи!). 2.  Нельзя разделять запятой подлежащее и сказуемое и нельзя согласовывать сказуемое с обособленным оборотом.  Вы согласны или нет?